# Verificacion de caracteres en MySql

Tags: sql, regex, caracteres

Muy buenas estimados;

Necesito su ayuda en este problema que tengo hecho en MySQL, tengo una variable X que tengo una cadena

```
X="inJks.88"
```

Ahora quiero hacer un `while` para revisar caracter por caracter toda la cadena, necesito que tenga:

- Una MAYUSCULA,
- Una miniscula,
- un Numero (0..9),
- un caracter especial (_-.+), ahora lo que no puede obtener es @ y espacios entremedio (| |)

si esta bien completo me va a salir Positivo, si incumple me sale Negativo

Cuando incumple:

- Cuando todo es minuscula
- Cuando todo es MAYUSCULA
- Cuando No se encuentre al menos un numero
- Cuando No se encuentre al menos un caracter especial

Por ejemplo:

```
X="inJks.88" POSITIVO
X="inJks88"  NEGATIVO  (no hay caracteres)
X="inks.88"  NEGATIVO  (no hay MAYÚSCULAS)
X="AA8.8SS"  NEGATIVO  (no hay minúsculas)
X="inksj."   NEGATIVO  (no hay Numero)
X="8.8"      NEGATIVO  (no hay MAYÚSCULA ni minúsculas)
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para verificar?

Comment: Deberías poner a la pregunta la etiqueta `regex`, para que algún experto en el tema te pueda ayudar. Es la mejor manera que veo para resolverlo.

Comment: Porque esta validacion la debe hacer la base de datos?

Comment: es una funcion que lo ejecuto desde un procedimiento almacenado si me sale positivo hace el registro a la BD del MySQL

Comment: Quien tiene conocimiento de SUBSTRING ( expression ,start , length )  , alguien me puede ayudar con esa función

Comment: Opino como gbianchi. Validar un password no debería ser resposabilidad de la bbdd. Si pretendes validar antes de insertar en bbdd, entonces ya se debería haber validado con anterioridad. Por ejemplo en la típica web con html, php y mysql, el código php sería el encargado de validar el password una vez se submite el formulario. Si el password es correcto se utilizaría en el insert.